# phpMyAdmin login fails in ubuntu 16.04 after installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

lamp stack installation completed following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

I'am getting this error

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have tried many solutions appeared, searching for the error in google.but nothing solved my issue.
eg : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/setup-mysql-on-ubuntu-droplet-getting-error-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost-using-password-yes

Can i get the right answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I uninstalled mysql-server then reinstalled with a different password also disallowed remote root login.
Then i installed phpmyadmin. Everythink went ok.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set disallow root login remotely while setting up mysql server? You can create new user on mysql and grant all privileges and login.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql